# Soft deletion in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to soft delete, no records are physically deleted from the database, just sets the IsDeleted filed to true.It would be more than one data with that value. In controller I add:

```
var res = (from c in db.Books
          where c.IsDeleted == 1
          select c);
```

And I don't know how to add a condition to a if clause. Tried

```
if (res != 1){
   return View(db.Books.ToList());
}
```

but it isn't. Has anyone have an idea what to do?

Comment: your query gets a single record where `IsDeleted == 1` and if there are multiple records it will throw an exception, is this what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to display data from a database which have in column IsDeleted  value of == 0.

Comment: so your query should be `where c.IsDeleted == 0` ??

Comment: FWIW, unless you're only ever going to have one item that is not deleted, then your query is going to result in `null`, *a lot*. If you just want a single item of many, use something like `FirstOrDefault`. `SingleOrDefault` will fail unless there is only a single matching result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

== checks for equality. if you want to set the IsDeleted field, you need something slightly different

try something like

```
var res = (from c in db.Books
      where c.Id == IdToFind).SingleOrDefault().IsDeleted = 1;
```

Disclaimer: Code may not be accurate, but should give ou an idea!